# Setup a maintenance URL in a generic way

Tags: networking, dns

Suppose I have a website that is normally accessed at address www.mywebsite.com.

Now let's say the website is down completely (think server has melted). I want the users trying to reach www.mywebsite.com to end up on a maintenance URL on another server instead of having a 404.

Is this possible easily without having to route all the trafic through a dispatcher/load balancer?

I could imagine something like :

When the default server is UP traffic is like :

[USER]<---->[www.mywebsite.com]<---->[DISPATCHER]<---->[DEFAULT SERVER]

When the default server is DOWN traffic is like :

[USER]<---->[www.mywebsite.com]<---->[DISPATCHER]<---->[MAINTENANCE SERVER]

Where [DISPATCHER] figures out where to route the traffic. Problem is that in this scenario  *all* the traffic goes through [DISPATCHER]. Can I make it so that the first connection goes through dispatcher, and then, if the default server is up, the traffic goes directly from the user to the default server? (with a check every 10 - 15 minutes for example)

[USER]<---->[www.mywebsite.com]<-------->[DEFAULT SERVER] after the first successful connection

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Unfortunately, maybe the most practical solution is to give-up. **Until browsers finally add support for SRV records....***

You can achieve what you want with dynamic DNS - setup some monitoring script on a "maintenance server" that would check if your website is down, and if yes, update DNS for your site and point it to the maintenance server. This approach have it's own problems,  biggest of which is that any monitoring may generate false positives, and thus your users will see the maintenance page while the site is actually up.

Another possible approach (even worse) - for example, make www.example.com point to your dispatcher server, and www2.example.com - to your main server. Then dispatcher would HTTP redirect all incoming requests to www2.example.com.

But what will you do when your *dispatcher* melts ? - While trying to handle one point of failure you just added another one.

Maybe it's practical to handle all page links in some javascript what will check if the server is up first, and only then follow the link. This approach while requires some scripting, but at least provides best results when your server is down while the user is already on your site. But it helps nothing for those who ry to enter the site for the first time.

***If only browsers would support SRV records....***